# How to select specific elements in span from @class xpath response

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am learning to use xpath in scrapy, but the html I am trying to scrape is quite complicated.

I have tried selecting some things with html, css and xpath but I have reached this:

`response.xpath('//span[starts-with(@class,"Animal-")]').getall()`

which returns:

`[u'<span class="Animal-1" title="Dogs" legs="4" tail="true"></span>', u'<span class="Animal-7" title="Birds" beak="true"></span>', u'<span class="Animal-24" title="Elephants"></span>']`

I used a separate script to just return the contents of the title element to get me going, but I know that this is a hacky solution. 
How can I return only the following:

```
Dogs
Birds
Elephants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath are very flexible you should learn more about them, below code will get you your result.

```
response.xpath('//span[starts-with(@class,"Animal-")]/@title').getall()
```

Cheers!!

Also you can test the above XPath [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ecf1b546d30d8e463c710f8a4b8e78fa), and play around to learn more, the above approach I have used works for all tag attributes, for example to extract href from all tags use `//a/@href`